# Should access token expire on logout in oauth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Oauth 2.0 provider. I am confused on access token grants. I am using oauth2orize module in node.js.

I am confused on Should I remove all access token related to specific user when user logouts from auth server? I am building mobile and single page app for browser and I am using Resource owner password credential flow. How long should access token be valid for and should it expire on logout?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an app will revoke an access token just prior to performing logout. Typically, the app will revoke a refresh token if it got one, as that will also invalidate any and all access tokens.

From the perspective of the authorization server, I would keep these things separate and implement both:

- Revoke ([RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009))
- Logout ([OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html))

Then, the clients can use either / both of these as they need. If you have some constraints in your environment, you may be able to automatically revoke tokens during logout in your authorization server. Generally though, an it should allow for both to be used independently and put the client in control.